# Is VMWare EXSI able to serve VM's through network?

Tags: virtualization, esxi

I would like to buid a server to host VM's. Users must be able to build/stop/run/use vm's through network. There would be something between 1-3 machines running at the same time.

The way I would like an user to interact with each vm is simple.He can build a vm if needed. He can start the machine and connect to it to start working inside it. The machines will be mainly used for developing. After the user finishes his work the machine will be switched off.

Is VMWare EXSI a good solution for this scenario? I have been checking some documentation and it seems to be a good solution but not sure.

Cheers

Comment: Are you asking if you can remotely manage vCenter?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, ESXI hypervisor can be reached by HTTP to manage it, so, if you create them account on the hypervisor, they will be able to create, manage and control any machine on the hypervisor with only a web browser.